# How can I handle an empty response through Alamofire .responseDecodable?

Tags: swift

I am trying to handle a response made through Alamofire and I am trying to decode an empty response. The documentation states that for `.responseDecodable` "no empty responses **unless allowed** by the emptyResponseMethods and emptyResponseCodes." I am not sure what emptyResponseMethods mean but this is what I have implemented so far.

```
struct EmptyResponse: Codable {}

AF.request(self.baseURL+route, method: method, parameters: body, encoder: parameterEncoder, headers: httpHeaders)
    .responseDecodable(of: successType, decoder: decoder, emptyResponseCodes: [204, 205]) { (response) in
        print("DEBUG: NetworkManager.responseDecodable \(response)")
        guard let success = response.value else { return }
        completionHandler(success)
    }
```

After I made a server request, the response is an `HTTP 204 Empty Response`.

I have another layer of abstraction for the variables you see here, but everything works out and I am focused on the `.responseDecodable`. I assume that if the `successType` is of `EmptyResponse` and with the `emptyResponseCodes`, I would be able to use `.responseDecodable`. It's not clear at all what the decoded response would be based on the documentation. I know that `.responseData` returns `.nil`.